# How to navigate between different nested ViewModels?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

I have a ViewModel Call Apple which has AppleItems. In the UI of the Apple ViewModel there is a nested ViewModel called AppleNote which has AppleNote items. When I am on the UI of the Apple ViewModel, there is an icon which lets me navigate into the AppleNote viewmodel. The way I am doing it is using eventagregators show in the code below. It is using binding as a DelegateCommand. My question is that when I am on Item#3 or any other item of AppleItems in Apple ViewModel and when I hit AppleNote for that Item it leads me into the right viewModel but when I want to switch back to the AppleItem view of that viewModel, I just get to the first item in the AppleItems. How can I tell that when going back to the AppleItems viewModel keep the item where you came from. If there is any confusion let me know so I can make it clear.

Here is a summary:

AppleViewModel-->Has-->AppleItems

```
             |

            Has--> AppleNoteViewModel-->Has-->AppleNotesItem
```

Going for a certain AppleItem to AppleNote is working but going back to the certain item is not working.

```
   private void AppleCommandExecute(object commandParameter)
    {

          _eventAggregator.Publish
            (new ChangeValueViewEventArgs
            {
                ViewModelType = typeof (AppleViewModel),


                Data = ValueId.ToString()
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As I implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface directly in my data classes, I don't have any nested view models, but I do have nested, or hierarchical data classes. In my base collection class, I have a property named `CurrentItem` of the same type as the items in the collection.

When I bind one of these collections to the `ItemsSource` property of a collection control, I also bind the `CurrentItem` property to the `SelectedItem` property of the control. This essentially means that I always know which is the current item in each collection.

If you implement one of these `CurrentItem` properties then you will always know which `AppleItem` or `AppleNote` is selected. You don't *have* to put these properties into collection classes... you could just add properties of the correct type to your view models instead. The point is that if you always bind to the `SelectedItem` property, then you will always know which item is selected.